# Detach a specified detail in csv using Pandas or something else

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning

I'm new to python, I use pandas to read log files in cvs format and the information I want to use is all in the raw column. Is there any way for me use pandas or something else to detach information such as "timestamp", "src_ip", "proto",... into separate columns or a new sheet ?

Raw column:

```
{"timestamp":"2022-12-05T21:12:45.189212+0700","flow_id":12004372636444,"in_iface":"em0","event_type":"dns","src_ip":"192.168.x.xx","src_port":56490,"dest_ip":"8.8.8.8","dest_port":53,"proto":"UDP","dns":{"type":"query","id":48818,"rrname":"e123456.api.splkmobile.com","rrtype":"AAAA","tx_id":0}}
```

I have searched for this problem on the internet but there is no solution, asking here is the last solution

Comment: Can you please also add an example line of the CSV file? I am not sure I get what you mean by raw column.

Comment: Are there multiple rows in the csv file that looks similar to the raw column shared in the question? Is the raw column the only column in the csv file? Please add the answers to this clarifying comment directly in the question. Please also share what you have tried to solve the question - see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).